# Limits in two variables

Tags: calculus

What is the value of the following limit? $$L=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (\alpha,0)}\left (1+\frac{x}{y} \right )^{y}$$

I rewrite the expression as$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (\alpha,0)}\left ( \left (1+\frac{x}{y} \right )^\frac{y}{x} \right )^\alpha$$ (as x tends to $\alpha$)

Setting $t=\frac{y}{x}$ the expression reduces to $M^{\alpha}$ where $$M= \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\left ( 1+\frac{1}{t} \right )^{t}$$

Now the limit of M exists and is equal to 1, I have two questions in this regard

1. If t approaches zero from the negative side, finding limit by taking natural logarithms would not be justified, while t, approaching from positive side, gives a limit of 1, so how does the limit exist and is equal to 1?
2. Assuming M=1, the value of L should be 1, however the textbook I am referring to shows the answer as $e^{\alpha}$

Comment: Notice that the limit is $\infnity^0$ so you should appmy L'hopitals rule

Comment: Yes, and that step would involve taking logarithms but for infinitesimally small and negative t, it is not defined, as the argument inside is negative .

Comment: Technically the limit doesn't exist $\lim (x,y) \to (\alpha, 0^-)$ doesn't exist for any path